# How long does it take for a review to appear in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

On Friday, I went into the App Store on my iPhone and submitted a review for a game.  I just checked all the reviews for that game, and my review hasn't appeared yet.  About how long does it take for a review to appear in the App Store?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/why-do-iphone-app-store-ratings-and-reviews-seem-to-get-processed-so-slowly

Comment: At least 1 week if you're lucky, at most 4 weeks. But usually around 2 weeks. Just set the launch date 4 weeks ahead if you want a countdown launch without failing like BBM.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it shouldn't appear immediately since more often than not, your [reviews](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3928) need to be approved before they are published by Apple for all to see.

Comment: I've submitted over 50 reviews and never once has one shown up immediately.

Comment: @bmike About how long does it take for your reviews to appear?

Comment: @pacoverflow I'd say between 24 hours and 2 weeks is the range which all that I've cared to check have arrived.

Comment: @bmike Like i mentioned more often than not they have to go through the approval. But the general time for reviews to appear is 24-48 hours.